# Bin with $52$ Colored Balls: $2$ Red, $2$ Yellow, $2$ Green, and $46$ Black; Probability of picking a Red, then a Yellow, then a Green

Tags: probability

I think the probability is $\left(\dfrac{2}{52}\right) \times \left(\dfrac{2}{51}\right)\times \left(\dfrac{2}{50}\right) $ or $\dfrac{8}{132}, 600$

Then the probability that I repeated the sequence: $ \left(\dfrac{1}{49}\right)\times \left(\dfrac{1}{48}\right)\times \left(\dfrac{1}{47}\right) $ or $\dfrac{1}{110},544$

The probability of doing all six would then be $\left(\dfrac{8}{132} ,600\right) \times \left(\dfrac{1}{110} ,544\right) $

Is this correct, and is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: Assuming that you're picking balls without replacement, both of your calculations appear correct.  Please use MathJax to render mathematics on the site.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is more elegant than your (correct) solution, but here's another approach.

There are $\binom{52}{6}$ subsets of $6$ balls.  If you draw $6$ balls without replacement, each subset is equally likely.  Therefore, the probability that you avoid all $46$ black balls for all $6$ draws is $\dfrac{1}{\binom{52}{6}}$.

Assuming that you avoid all $46$ black balls, you need to calculate the probability that you draw the balls in the desired order.  That probability is $\frac 26 \cdot \frac 25 \cdot \frac 24 \cdot \frac 13 \cdot \frac 12 = \frac {1}{90}$.  So the probability of drawing RYGRYG in that order is $\dfrac{1}{90 \binom{52}{6}}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that for the size of this particular problem, the method you have adopted is most transparent, and optimal, but suppose in a similar problem, the initial string was of a length $20$, say, it would be a bit irksome.

There is more than one way to skin a cat, so a not more elegant nor more transparent, but more "standard" approach, perhaps, would be to use

$${Choose\;6\;desired\; \div\; Permutations\; of\; the\; 6\over Choose\;any\;6} \quad\quad= \frac{1/\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}}{52\choose 6}$$